# Does Resource Owner Password Credentials (ROPC) work with "ad hoc" users?

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, oauth, azure-active-directory, office365

I'm trying to wrap my head around the limitations of the [ROPC authentication flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc).

If I set up an Azure app, can I then sign in any user that has an Office 365 account using the ROPC flow, or do I need to add the user to my Azure app first?

In [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-ropc?tabs=app-reg-ga), Microsoft says that

> ROPC supports local accounts only. Users can’t sign in with federated identity providers like Microsoft, Google+, Twitter, AD-FS, or Facebook.

I'm not sure what they mean by "local accounts"? Is that an account that has already been added as a user to my Azure app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A local account is an account that was originally created in that AAD tenant.
Any invited guest user does not count.
Though I have heard ROPC sometimes working with AD users who have been synced (which are technically not local users), but that depended on the setup.